# How to build grid lines with 2 arrays with map function in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native

Please click image to view detail

[image: 1]

Like this image I have 2 arrays that :

```
array_one: [409, 410, 411, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425]

array_two: [NN, NM, NL, NK, NJ]
```

Noted: use map function to create this grid lines. array_one become row and array_two become column. Next when user onPress on one grid lines then show the value (ex: NM411)

I try it by I used map function to create it. but i can't show value from index that get value from array_one and array two.

code:

```
{array_one.map((valone, index) => (
        array_two.map((val, index) => (
          <View style={{width: 35, height: 15, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 10}}>{val + valone}</Text>
          </View>
        )
        )
      )
      )}
```

Comment: Please provide a codesandbox or smthg that show your attempt...

Comment: Hello @johannchopin, i add code already that i try to do it. Please help me a bit. Thanks

Comment: You should not do a sum of a string and a number in javascript. Try with `{val}{valone}` instead.